# How to store image retrieved from url in a SQLite database?

Tags: android

I am retrieving images from a url. 
Instead of caching the images, would it by any chance be possible to store it in a SQLite database?

```
                /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }





                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                try {

                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();

                                conn.connect();

                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */

                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();
                                Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                        }

                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));
                return i;
                }
                else{
                    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                    return i;
                }

                }

                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
                }
                }
```

EDIT: Set the imageAdapter to load images in Gallery

```
((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                          .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));
```

Comment: Why not store them on the sdcard?

Comment: Could you provide an example from the code i have above? Or a tutorial you know. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected Drawable Imagehandler(String url) {
        try {
            url=url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            InputStream is = (InputStream)this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {   
            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println("error at URI"+e);
            return null;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("io exception: "+e);
            System.out.println("Image NOT FOUND");
            return null;
        } 
    }

    protected Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

this will convert your imageUrl to Drawble at runtime, then set the Drawble to Imageview of Gallery

Comment: So how would this integrate with my code in the question? Would i replace the imageLoader extending the base adapter?

Answer (score 5):

ya you can store image as BLOB in your database,

```
public static byte[] urlToImageBLOB(String url) throws IOException {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        entity = null;
        httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            entity = response.getEntity();
        }
        return EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
    }
```

To fetch

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromBLOB(byte[] mBlob) {
        byte[] bb = mBlob;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);

    }
```

// to set    `imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageFromBLOB(cursor.getBlob(object.getColumnIndex("book_thumb"))));`

Comment: So the entity will be saved in the database? Ive pasted the code im using to retreive the images above.

Comment: no, you have to take field as Blob here (book_thumb)
ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
value.put("book_thumb", urlToImageBLOB(url));
db.insertOrThrow(Table_name, null,value);
this will save your image to DB as BLOB

Comment: How would i go about retreiving it? Or would it be better to save it to a SDCard like Kaj said on the comment abov?

Comment: Would this work for the code i am using to fetch the images? See the edited question. Im using a gallery

Comment: but mine one was good, as it will stored at local storage, so fast navigation can be done

Comment: Would this work for the code i am using to fetch the images? See the edited question. Im using a gallery

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to how you store data in external storage: [External storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

The link explains where to place files (if you want to use external storage), and how to check if external storage is available.

Edit: How you access files, is explained under the topic "Accessing files on external storage".

You should in API 8, or above invoke `getExternalFilesDir()` to get a `File` that represents your applications root directory. You can then read and write the files as you normally do (using e.g. FileWriter and FileReader for text data)

Comment: The link doesn't tell you how to save to the sdcard. just check availability?