# "setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath)" get image from web server Android

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am using the the gridView example from the developer.android.com site. But they are using images saved in the res/drawable folder. I want to try and set the images to come from my web server.

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds={

        for(int i=0;i<myJSONArray.lenght();i++){
            Object[] myJSONArray;
            setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(String "www.mywebsite.com: + myJSONArray[i]).thumb);
        };

};
```

Am I on the correct path to accomplish this? I am looking for advice or documentations/tutorials on this process. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way you cant create Drawable from internet, for that you have first download content & make it Drawable refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815355/how-to-store-image-retreived-from-url-in-a-sqlite-database/6815819#6815819)

Comment: +1 I will take a look at the full post. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Your link was very helpful and answered the question I had. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the [GreenDroid](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240) library to do it for me - it has a nice set of imageloading classes.  It takes some slight modification if you don't want to use their actionbar (I didn't see an easy way to do it without modification).  Everything is also async : D !

Comment: [This is also another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)