# ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter, layout-inflater

Hi i'm new bee to android.
while executing my application I'm getting nullpoint exception error, dont know why it is happening. please any one help me to get rid from this issue. thanks in advance.

**This is my logcat:**

```
09-14 12:30:14.027: INFO/System.out(365): Constructor StudentList Adapter...
09-14 12:30:14.027: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(365): Shutting down VM
09-14 12:30:14.027: WARN/dalvikvm(365): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.UserLogin/com.UserLogin.FindPlaces}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.UserLogin.FindPlaces.displayLocs(FindPlaces.java:35)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.UserLogin.FindPlaces.onCreate(FindPlaces.java:30)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-14 12:30:14.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     ... 18 more
09-14 12:30:14.057: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.UserLogin/.Innerpage
09-14 12:30:14.594: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4506eef0 com.UserLogin/.Innerpage}
09-14 12:30:16.347: INFO/Process(365): Sending signal. PID: 365 SIG: 9
09-14 12:30:16.367: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Process com.UserLogin (pid 365) has died.
09-14 12:30:16.367: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{4506a6e0 com.UserLogin/com.UserLogin.Innerpage paused=false}
09-14 12:30:16.367: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{451492d0 com.UserLogin/com.UserLogin.UserLogin paused=false}
09-14 12:30:16.397: INFO/UsageStats(58): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.UserLogin
```

**Java file:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindPlaces extends ListActivity{

    private SQLiteDatabase DbLoc;
    ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<Fields> results = new ArrayList<Fields>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        //setContentView(R.layout.places);
        getallLocs();
        displayLocs();

    }
    private void displayLocs() {
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPlaces);
        lv.setAdapter(new StudentListAdapter(this, R.layout.placeslist, results));

        //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Fields>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

    }
    class StudentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fields>{
        private ArrayList<Fields> locationDetails;
        private Context mContext;

        public StudentListAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Fields> results) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, results);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            System.out.println("Constructor StudentList Adapter...");
            this.locationDetails = results;
            mContext = context;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return results.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fields getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return locationDetails.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                LayoutInflater vl = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vl.inflate(R.layout.placeslist, null);
            }
                            Fields o = results.get(position);

            if (o != null) {

                TextView iv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                TextView tv_sNo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext1);
                iv.setText(o.getLocationName());                            
                tv_sNo.setText(o.getLocationImage());   

            }
            DbLoc.close();
            return v;
        }       
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView Locationname;
        ImageView Locationimage;
    }
    private void getallLocs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(
                    this.getApplicationContext());
            DbLoc = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = DbLoc.rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.LocationName+ " , " + DatabaseHelper.LocationImage + " FROM "
                    + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONTABLE , null);
                            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String LocationName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LocationName"));
                        String Mobile = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("LocationImage"));
                        Fields p = new Fields(LocationName, Mobile);
                        results.add(p);

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "Could not create or Open the database");
        } 
        finally { if (DbLoc != null) DbLoc.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +
                DatabaseHelper.FRIENDTABLE); DbLoc.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +
                        DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONTABLE);  
                DbLoc.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename"+ DatabaseHelper.FRIENDTABLE);
                DbLoc.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename"+ DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONTABLE);
                DbLoc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Places.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="6dip">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listPlaces" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Placeslist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uncomment this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.places);
```

**EDITED**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="6dip">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

replace this with your file(Places.xml)

**UPDATED**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        //setContentView(R.layout.places);
        getallLocs();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Fields>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
//        displayLocs();

    }
    private void displayLocs() {
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPlaces);
        lv.setAdapter(new StudentListAdapter(this, R.layout.placeslist, results));

        //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Fields>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

    }
```

Comment: after uncommenting getting

09-14 12:49:50.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

in logcat

Comment: after replacing places.xml file 
 lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPlaces);
this will be error.

Comment: yes. i've removed that line
now getting 


09-14 14:13:54.206: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: yes. i've replaced with your edited xml file, and now i've build my project once and checked now getting this error :::: 09-14 14:28:09.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.UserLogin/com.UserLogin.FindPlaces}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 14:28:09.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: comment displayLocs(); method

Comment: If i comment displayLocs(); method then i'll not get display the locations.

Comment: Thanks for your posts. It's really got my solution.. and one more how can i display an image with image url.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815355/how-to-store-image-retreived-from-url-in-a-sqlite-database/6815819#6815819 and finally http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @hotveryspicy with your editecode layoutinflating is not happening.. its just displaying in default simple_list_item_1..

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `findViewById()` if you haven't set a content-view for the activity. So your `lv` will be null.

---

You're using a `ListActivity`. If you want to add your own style to it, the `ListView` in your layout needs the id `android:list`:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
  ...
/>
```

As illustrated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

If you use a `ListActivity`, you don't use `findViewById()` to get the ListView, you can use the [`getListView()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29).

Comment: after replacing places.xml file lv = 

(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPlaces);

this will be error.

Comment: If you use a `ListActivity`, and you want to customize it, the `ListView` needs the above id. You can access it in Java by using the [`getListView()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView())

Comment: I've commented this above line and i'm just calling adapter---- lv.setAdapter(new StudentListAdapter(this, R.layout.placeslist, results));------ now i'm getting --- 14 14:28:09.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.UserLogin/com.UserLogin.FindPlaces}: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-14 14:28:09.247: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks for your posts. It's really got my solution.. and one more how can i display an image with image url.

Comment: with @hotveryspicy help i can able to get values to listview. But i need those values in custom list view. I want to display those values by inflating layout. can you please help me.

Comment: You might want to create a new question for that... and use google.