# Posting web image to Glass card

Tags: android, drawable, google-glass, google-mirror-api

Android noob trying to figure out how exactly to do this. The goal is simple: grab an image file from the web (with a URL) and put that image onto a Google Glass card.

I have a function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815355/how-to-store-image-retreived-from-url-in-a-sqlite-database/6815819#6815819) that creates a drawable from a web url.

However, when I try to create a Google Glass card, the method card.AddImage(uri) requires a URI. I have a drawable object created from the method referenced above - how do I put this drawable object onto the card?

Is there a way to extract the URI from the drawable object? Most of the questions here deal with extracting the URI of a local resource, and since this drawable object was created "on the fly" during execution, I'm not sure how to apply URI.parse in such a situation (I don't have an absolute path to the resource).

Is this even the right approach? Should I be creating a drawable, or is there a way to retrieve the image strictly using a URI of that web address?

Comment: Would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602417/get-the-uri-of-an-image-stored-in-drawable

Comment: Why not simply use the URI you created in the first question?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, how would I get that? I have a function (from another question referenced above) that makes a Drawable of the web image, but the function I need to display the image requires a URI as its parameter.

Comment: You don't have to fetch the content for that purpose. Simply use card.addImage(new URL(address)); where address is the string with web address of the image

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going through more work to try to get a web-available image onto a card.  Why not simply use the original web image rather than the `drawable` you have created `(card.addImage(new URL(address))`?  If you need to process the image, then you would want to store it in a web available manner on your server side where you are hosting your google-mirror-api code. See the Glass sample that adds an image of a cat to a picture taken by Glass and reposts it.