# Android - Fetch data from SQLite and display in ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to fetch data from SQLite and then I want to display it on my ListView, I think I'm confused or misunderstanding how to do it properly... The thing that I've done is :

1.-Create an `Insert` into a `Table` from `SQLite` (This is working).

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO T_OFERTA VALUES (1, 1, 'Offer1', 30, '2x1', '30, 10-1-2013', '1-1-2013', 'Descripció del producte pew', 1, 'http://www.canon.es/Images/Android-logo_tcm86-1232684.png')");
```

2.-On my `ListFragment` I've created : 1 `ImageView`, 3 `Strings` and 1 `Integer`. This is made because on my `Adapter` I need a `Drawable`, `String` and `Integer`.

```
 ImageView FOTO;
 String Title, percent, data_f;
 Integer Preu;
```

3.-I made a cursor that is like this :

```
Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("Select NOM_OFER,PREU_OFERTA,DATA_F,FOTO, PERCENTDESCOMPTE from T_OFERTA", null);
c.moveToFirst();
if (c != null) {
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
            Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
            percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
            data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));
            FOTO = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("FOTO"))); // <--- Error because FOTO it's an ImageView....
            Log.e("", "" + c.getString(i));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Title" + Title + "Preu" + Preu + "Percent" + percent + "Cheese is " + data_f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```

Now I've to put the data of my variables inside of :

```
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.zumo_oferta), getString(R.string.pew), getString(R.string.pew_precio), getString(R.string.pew_descuento), getString(R.string.pew_data)));
```

My `ListViewItem` class looks like:

```
    public class ListViewItem {
    public final Drawable icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;       // the text for the ListView item title
    public final String precio;      // the price for the ListView item
    public final String descuento;   // the price for the discount for the ListView item
    public final String date;        //the date for the sale for the ListView item
     // the text for the ListView item description

    public ListViewItem(Drawable icon, String title, String precio, String descuento, String date) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.descuento = descuento;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And my `ListViewDemoAdapter` looks like :

```
  public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

    public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate the GridView item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            // initialize the view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            viewHolder.tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiscount);
            viewHolder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDatas);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycle the already inflated view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // update the item view
        ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDiscount.setText(item.descuento);
        viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(item.precio);
        viewHolder.tvDate.setText(item.date);

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDiscount;
        TextView tvPrice;
        TextView tvDate;
    }
}
```

This is made because I wanted to see if the fetch was doing correctly.

### TL;DR

*I'm not using any `BaseAdapter`, neither a `BitMapAdapter`, and since I've to use an URL to set as `ImageView` I don't know if it would work, then my question is, can I do it by the way I'm doing this at the moment, or shall I create a `BitMapAdater` instead of `Drawable`? If I do by this way, I can not use the string that I get as a "FOTO" --> Image, because it is not a `Drawable` and it's a `String`...
Can you guide to me to do this properly, that was make because it was just a test, now I want to set the ListView with data of my SQLite.*

If you didn't understand my question or just need more code, let me know I'll reply you as soon as possible.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: How can I put the data from my SQLite on my ListView, if there is more than 1 product? At the moment I have Inserted 1, but I'll create more, where I've to put the mItems.add? Since I've got an ImageView on my Adapter and on my SQLite I've got a String (URL) I can't pass the data... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the following:

1. To make it easier, create `ListViewItem`s as they are retrieved:

   ```
   ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
   for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
       Title = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("NOM_OFER")));
       Preu = c.getColumnIndex("PREU_OFERTA");
       percent = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTDESCOMPTE")));
       data_f = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("DATA_F")));

       // create and add your items as they are retrieved from the db
       myItems.add(new ListViewItem(...,Title, Preu, percent, data_f));

       ...
   } ...
   ```

Now that you've got all the items out of your database you can easily pass them into your `ListView`/`adapter`:

```
myAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), myItems);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

2. I wouldn't store a `Drawable` in your `ListViewItem`, instead just store the resource id as an integer:

   ```
   int icon = R.drawable.example_icon;
   ```

Then handle the conversion to the actual image resource in your adapter's `getView()` method:

```
ivIcon.setImageResource(item.icon);
```

Comment: See what I've added... the thing is that I want to add the "FOTO" that is an ImageView inside of my ListView... but since I declared on my adapter that is an ImageView i don't know how to pass the url to an ImageView...

Comment: @Skizo since you're storing the url of an actual image (this was unclear when I wrote my answer), consider using something like [what this answer suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6815819/745750) to handle the conversion (you can use change ImageView back to a Drawable here).